# Can't import media wordpress - Failed to import Media "xxx”

Tags: wordpress

Trying to import media from an old domain to my new server with a new domain.  After running the importer and selecting "upload attachments" it fails with multiple "Failed to import Media" errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps I took (which are probably essentially what the importer plugin is trying to do):

1 - Delete the following tables on the new server using PhpMyAdmin: wp_postmeta, wp_posts

2  - Import these tables from the old server

3 - Copy all files from the wp-content/uploads folder from the old to the new server.

Note: It may be possible to import posts using the plugin and skipping the delete and import of the wp_posts table.  Need to confirm.

**Notes:**
If you are running a Bitnami image for your wordpress server, in order to access PhpMyAdmin, you have to use reverse port tunnel your website url to 127.0.0.1:8888.  In the command line this is:

$ `ssh -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80 username@www.newwebsite.com`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your hosting have available space and Wordpress has the right permissions.